# Javascript RegEx : Match repeating character exactly twice (ignore if it matches 3 times)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am parsing strings for tokens that have 2 types of delimiter (similar to mustache templates).

I need a pure reg ex solution that matches `{{bob}}` in `this is {{bob}} a double token`. But does NOT match in `this is {{{bob}}} a triple token`

I am matching the double with

```
\{\{[^\{]([\s\S]+?)[^\}]\}\}
```

However, it matches the `{{bob}}` within the triple `{{{bob}}}`.

Without the negative look behind i'm struggling to find a pure regex solution.  Any pointers?

Comment: You want to replace `{{bob}}` with something? What should be output for `{{{bob}}` and `{{bob}}}`?

Comment: yes, they will get replaced with a string. But i cant match the double without also unintentionally matching the triple.

Comment: `(?<!{){{bob}}(?!})` Why can't you use lookahead/behind?

Comment: [`.replace(/({{{.*?}}})|{{(.*?)}}/g, (m, $1, $2) => $1 ? $1 : 'Bob the Builder')`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ua9rurqc/)

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara [Not supported by JS](https://regex101.com/r/uM8ERa/1)

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, its the look behind that is causing me the issues

Comment: @MattBryson: Are you replacing or extracting? Look, Tushar already showed you an example how to skip triple bracketed strings when replacing. You actually can harvest all the Group 2 values into an array inside the anonymous method.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, as always its never that simple :)  This is a RegEgx that is fed into an existing library that I have no control over. It requires one matching group in the reg ex, which is then used to evaluate some expressions and replace the entire match.   I'll update the post with a solution and more details once I've had time to look at it again.

Comment: @Matt You will not be able to solvetit with a pure regex  then. Without a lookbehind you will need to modify or adjust the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could search any whitespace char outside the brackets, something like this:

`\s(\{\{([^\{\}]+?)\}\})\s`

Answer (score 0):

**RegEx:** 
`^(\}?)\{\{[^\{]([\s\S]+?)[^\}]\}\}`

**Auto Generated Explanation:**

`^ asserts position at start of the string
1st Capturing Group (\}?)
\}? matches the character } literally (case sensitive)
? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\{ matches the character { literally (case sensitive)
\{ matches the character { literally (case sensitive)
Match a single character not present in the list below [^\{]
\{ matches the character { literally (case sensitive)
2nd Capturing Group ([\s\S]+?)
Match a single character present in the list below [\s\S]+?
+? Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
\S matches any non-whitespace character (equal to [^\r\n\t\f ])
Match a single character not present in the list below [^\}]
\} matches the character } literally (case sensitive)
\} matches the character } literally (case sensitive)
\} matches the character } literally (case sensitive)
Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)`

Comment: Thats almost it, but it still matches the double brackets within the triple, how can I exclude that, so it ONLY matches the double?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following to extract the matches:

```js
var s = "this is {{{ bad bob triple}}} a triple token {{bob double}} {{bob}} a double token {{{bad token}}  {{bad token}}}";
var rx = /(?:^|[^{]){{([^{}]*)}}(?!})/g;
var m, res=[];
while(m=rx.exec(s)) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/3NIn2W/1).

- `(?:^|[^{])` - either start of string or any char but `{`
- `{{` - double `{`
- `([^{}]*)` - Group 1: any char but `{` and `}` zero or more times
- `}}` - double `}`
- `(?!})` - not followed immediately with `}`.